# Can I use a variable in a GLM that was modeled using another model

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, interpretation, independence

I would like to know how to interpret following linear model:
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{1i} + \beta_2 X_{2i} + \beta_3 X_{3i}   \tag{1}
$$
Now assume that variable $X_2$ is the result of another model:
$$
X_{2i}'= Y_{2i}' = \beta_0' + B_1'X_{3i}  \tag{2}
$$
from the subset of data used for first model.

Can we use that kind of variable in the first model? Because from my point of view we are violating assumption of independence of the the explanatory variables (because $X_2$ and $X_3$ are dependent).

Can you please explain how this can be interpreted?

Comment: What do you mean that $2$ was "from the subset of data used for first model"? Do you have the same amount of data for both models? Are they fitted to the same dataset or different datasets? Are you thinking about an imputation scheme for missing data? Are you thinking of [two-stage least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumental_variable#Interpretation_as_two-stage_least_squares) to assess causality using an instrument?

Comment: This can get tricky really fast. $X_{3i}$ has a direct effect on $Y_i$ (namely, $\beta_3$) but also has an indirect effect on $Y_i$ through it's effect on $X_{2i}$. Depending on what you want, you may need to do a mediation analysis.

Also, side comment: There is no assumption about dependence in general. The assumption is that there can be no *perfect* *linear* dependence between two variables.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to do this? Can't you just fit 
$$Y_i = \beta_0'' + \beta_1X_{1i} + \beta_3''X_{3i}$$

with $\beta_0''=\beta_0 + \beta_0'$ and $\beta_3''=\beta_3 +  B_1'$?

There is no assumption of independence between explanatory variables in regression, but it is true that it can lead to problems of multicollinearity if the correlation is too strong.